# How can I run Python's Matlab Engine API on a Server

Tags: python, matlab, deployment, matlab-deployment

I have access to Matlab on my PC and able to run my Matlab Function on the Matlab Engine API on Python.

My question is how can I do the same on a Hosted Server and run the Fucntion. How do I install and locate Matlab. Do I need some sort of License Key?

For example:
`

```
import matlab.engine
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
tf = eng.isprime(37)
print(tf)`
```

I tried running the given example on a Python compiler and was able to do so, unable to run it on a server.